# When does an inhibitor death increase minion HP?

Tags: league-of-legends

When an inhibitor dies it increases the HP of minions, but does it increase the HP of the minions already on the map or does it increase the HP of the next few waves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Destroying an inhibitor causes *future groups of minions* to have super minions and gives future waves a boost of around 100 hit points. It doesn't affect current waves.

More info can be found on the [LoL Wikia site](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Inhibitor).